# CSS drop down menu broke

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have a hoverable drop down menu where sub links are supposed to be open to the right. This code has remained the same for couple of years now and it's been working. Now I added a new sub link and the code broke.

This is menu's code:

```css
#divMenu, ul, li, li li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#divMenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 27px;
}
#divMenu ul {
  line-height: 50px;
}
#divMenu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  font-size:20px;
}
#divMenu li li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  left: 148px;
  top: -27px;
  font-size:12px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#divMenu ul li a {
  width: 148px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',serif;
  color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #2d2d2d;
}
#divMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 27px;
}
#divMenu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#divMenu li:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#divMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#divMenu a:hover {
  font-weight: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMenu">
  <li><a href="index.php">Etusivu</a></li>
  <li><a href="kissala.php">Kissala</a></li>
  <li><a href="mainecoon.php">Maine Coon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Herrat</a>
    <ul>
      <li><p style="font-size:10px;margin:0px"><a href="hermann.php">Macawi 
    Mosi Double E´s Xahir</a></p></li>
      <li><a href="leo.php">Vuorensinen Baloo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ladyt</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="sura.php">Blackcurrant Sophia Loren</a></li>
     <li><a href="hilde.php">Bloomingtree QQ`Sweetest Taboo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Kastraatit</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="luna.php">Artsycats Lucy In The Sky</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pennut</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="varattavissa.php">Varattavissa</a></li>
      <li><a href="suunnitelmat.php">Suunnitelmat</a></li>
     <li><a href="pentuinfo.php">Pentuinfo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pentueet</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="vintagestar.php">Vintage Star -pentue</a></li>
     <li><a href="oldwest.php">Old West -pentue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linkit.php">Linkit</a></li>
  <li><a href="yhteystiedot.php">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://users4.smartgb.com/g/g.php?a=s&i=g44-74607-
  71">Vieraskirja</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I've added one more sub-link there and even if I remove it, the code won't work.

[image]

*Screen cap: the sub links are shown all the time - not with hovering*

Comment: What sub-link did you add?

Comment: We need some more info, what did you add and how is it broken?

Comment: I added: <li><a href="hilde.php">Bloomingtree QQ`Sweetest Taboo</a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the starting `<ul>` tag after `<div id="divMenu">` . Adding `<ul>` after `<div id="divMenu">` shall fix it for you.

```css
#divMenu, ul, li, li li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#divMenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 27px;
}
#divMenu ul {
  line-height: 50px;
}
#divMenu li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  font-size:20px;
}
#divMenu li li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  left: 148px;
  top: -27px;
  font-size:12px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#divMenu ul li a {
  width: 148px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',serif;
  color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #2d2d2d;
}
#divMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 27px;
}
#divMenu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#divMenu li:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#divMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#divMenu a:hover {
  font-weight: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMenu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Etusivu</a></li>
  <li><a href="kissala.php">Kissala</a></li>
  <li><a href="mainecoon.php">Maine Coon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Herrat</a>
    <ul>
      <li><p style="font-size:10px;margin:0px"><a href="hermann.php">Macawi 
    Mosi Double E´s Xahir</a></p></li>
      <li><a href="leo.php">Vuorensinen Baloo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ladyt</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="sura.php">Blackcurrant Sophia Loren</a></li>
     <li><a href="hilde.php">Bloomingtree QQ`Sweetest Taboo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Kastraatit</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="luna.php">Artsycats Lucy In The Sky</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pennut</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="varattavissa.php">Varattavissa</a></li>
      <li><a href="suunnitelmat.php">Suunnitelmat</a></li>
     <li><a href="pentuinfo.php">Pentuinfo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pentueet</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="vintagestar.php">Vintage Star -pentue</a></li>
     <li><a href="oldwest.php">Old West -pentue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="linkit.php">Linkit</a></li>
  <li><a href="yhteystiedot.php">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://users4.smartgb.com/g/g.php?a=s&i=g44-74607-
  71">Vieraskirja</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing opening element ul at first. just change your html code to below :

```html
<div id="divMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Etusivu</a></li>

            <li><a href="kissala.php">Kissala</a></li>

            <li><a href="mainecoon.php">Maine Coon</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Herrat</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p style="font-size:10px;margin:0px">
                            <a href="hermann.php">
                                Macawi
                                Mosi Double E´s Xahir
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="leo.php">Vuorensinen Baloo</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Ladyt</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="sura.php">Blackcurrant Sophia Loren</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hilde.php">Bloomingtree QQ`Sweetest Taboo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Kastraatit</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="luna.php">Artsycats Lucy In The Sky</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Pennut</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="varattavissa.php">Varattavissa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="suunnitelmat.php">Suunnitelmat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pentuinfo.php">Pentuinfo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Pentueet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="vintagestar.php">Vintage Star -pentue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="oldwest.php">Old West -pentue</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="linkit.php">Linkit</a></li>
            <li><a href="yhteystiedot.php">Yhteystiedot</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://users4.smartgb.com/g/g.php?a=s&i=g44-74607-
71">Vieraskirja</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The <ul> tag really solved my problem. I don't know how I could not see the mistake myself.